# Deny access to subfolders and files using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following directory structure

```
localhost_foler
 |__test
      |
      |__d1/
      |   |__f1.html
      |
      |__d2/
      |
      |__d3/
      |
      |__d4/
      |
      |__.htaccess
```

What I want to achieve is to deny access to all files in `d2`, `d3` and `d4` but allow them to be included by php files. Also for `d1`, excluding the file `f1.html` the rest needs to be blocked.

**Requirement**: Only a **single** `.htaccess` file in the `test` dir.

What I tried:

```
Options -Indexes

<Files "d1/*">
    Deny From All
</Files>

<FilesMatch "^f1\.html">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files "d2/*">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files "d3/*">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files "d4/*">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From 127.0.0.1    
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rewriteRule to forbid access to  files inside the folders :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/d1/f1\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(d1|d2|d3|d4)/.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, but maybe you missed the other part, I also want to disable all but one file for d1, what will the condition be like for that? I havn't use rewrite cond before, so i hope you don't mind me asking this.

Comment: @feetnappy Your welcome! I have updated the code as per your request. Added a look-ahead based regex to exclude the file from the rule.

Comment: Thank you for responding but your condition is not working. The problem is f1 is in d1 and not in other folders. Will that need a different rewrite cond? Sorry for asking so much.